# Is this definition of constexpr offset_of is correct according to the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

I wonder if this definition of a constexpr `offset_of` is correct according to the c++11 standard.

According to [this article](http://thecppzoo.blogspot.ca/2016/10/constexpr-offsetof-practical-way-to.html), C++98 allowed conversion in a declaration of an array. I tweaked the code in the article to allow some of my cases. Can I do the following? If not, is there a better way?

```
template<typename T>
struct declval_helper { static T value; };

template<typename T, typename Z, typename U, Z U::*MPtr>
struct offset_helper {
    using TV = declval_helper<T>;

    static char for_sizeof[1 + (
        (char *)&(TV::value.*MPtr) -
        (char *)&TV::value
    )];
};

template<typename T, typename Z, typename U, Z U::*MPtr>
constexpr std::size_t offset_of() {
    return sizeof(detail::offset_helper<T, Z, U, MPtr>::for_sizeof) - 1;
}
```

A use case:

```
struct Base { int data; };
struct Derived : Base { float data; };

constexpr std::size_t offset = offset_of<Derived, int, Base, &Base::data>();
```

Comment: No, it's not. The array bound must be a constant expression, and the  `reinterpret_cast` implied in the C-style cast cannot be part of one.

Comment: @Columbo if I move the array declaration in the constexpr function, the compiler tells me it's not a constant expression. However, when declared in the class, it works both in clang and gcc without warning.

Comment: @Guillaume Did you use `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors`?

Comment: @cpplearner you can see for yourself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/754d727287b9c205

Comment: It even works with explicit reinterpret casts: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/387ce964e123b62a

Comment: Compiling with `-pedantic` and clang gives: `"warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]"` (complaining about `for_sizeof`)

Comment: The question doesn't specify according to what standard: C++11 or C++98.

What the article is stating that it is tricking the C++11 compiler into compiling the template-struct  as C++98, and thus gets it past the compiler. It seems the complete code is illegal according to both, for different reasons.

Comment: @HansOlsson I updated the question. Yes, it's according to the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's ill-formed.

From [dcl.array]:

> If the *constant-expression* (5.20) is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type `std::size_t` and its value shall be greater than
>   zero.

The *constant-expression* here refers to the array bound, which is optional. A converted constant expression is, from [expr.const]:

> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant expression [...]

and a constant expression is:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions: [...] — a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10);

This declaration:

```
static char for_sizeof[1 + (
    (char *)&(TV::value.*MPtr) -
    (char *)&TV::value
)];
```

uses an implicit `reinterpret_cast` in the array bound of an array, which makes it not a constant expression, so it's ill-formed.